# guard not recognizing file changes on windows share mounted in Ubuntu using samba

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, guard

I have my rails application file on my windows Host OS where I like to edit it with sublime text 2.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 in a VirtualBox VM with a host-only network adapter.
I use the Ubuntu OS guest for my development environment other than simply editing the rails application files. (i.e. rails commands, mysql, rvm...)

The rails app directory is mounted on my Ubuntu file system via samba.  However, guard (running in Ubuntu) doesn't detect the file changes through the samba share.

I'm not sure how to send the file changes so that guard can recognize them through the samba share.

Answer (score 0):

The advise from the wiki:

> Use Listen's network functionality to receive file change events from the network. This is most useful for virtual machines (e.g. Vagrant) which have problems firing native filesystem events on the guest OS.

And listening on the port

[Guard wiki](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Command-line-options-for-Guard#running-guard-in-a-vm)

Comment: The problem is my code is in a windows ntfs directory.  Under the listen installation instructions for windows, it says:  Robust Windows installation instructions needed.